# Meaning of Event in php

Tags: php, events, event-handling

I know php and nodejs too,in javascript we have asynchronize programming ,so I understand meaning of event in it.but I saw **Event in Yii and Zend 2** and use them too,but I can't understand the meaning of it,how it works in php and what exactly does in it?

Comment: Using it in framework is so easy,I use thems ones without knowing what actully done.

Comment: How [events](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.event.php) can be useful for a simple `<?php echo 'Hello World.'; ?>` script?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP, it's an event system implemented by these frameworks.

Comment: i would also like to know the answer can anyone explain in detail and the what are the uses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### First of all, there are no events in PHP

An event is an abstraction for callback functions with their name. 
Typically, we'd define them as `$eventName => $listener`, where `$listener` is a callback function for the `$eventName`

### What is the difference between events and regular callback functions?

Again - the core point to remember, is that events are callback functions. Nothing more.

The only difference between them, is how we do invoke them.

> > <sub>An event is defined on bootstrap step with its required arguments, but invoked on demand without arguments. While the callback function is invoked with arguments and only</sub>

Consider this example,

```
<?php

$eventManager = new EventManager();
$eventManager->attach('my_event', function(){

   print_r(func_get_args());

}, array('foo', 'bar'));
```

As we have just defined an event, we'd invoke like,

`$eventManager->trigger('my_event');`

This will output: `Array([0] => [foo], [1] => [bar]`

### That's related to JavaScript!

Since most of us are familiar with JavaScript even-driven architecture, its worth nothing to mention an example of its common usage:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
a.onclick = function(event) { // <-- We define an event with the event argument
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('A element was clicked');
}

a.click(); // <-- but we invoke it without arguments

// or If you want a Jquery
$("a").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('A element was clicked');
});

$("a").click();
```

Since in PHP we don't have such event-driven nature, we can replace it with our own class that manage events and takes a full advantage of it.

### Why use them?

While events confuse so many people, they are extremely useful.

Imagine you have a **Content Management System (CMS)**, where your users can decide how to handle `404` errors. Say, they can handle with

1) Show a blank page 
2) Redirect to `/` 
3) Show a custom message

Without events you would have to do it, like

```
if ($router->isMatched($request)){

    //do dispatch etc

} else {

   // Here you start handling 404 errors

   switch($config->read('404_way_handle')){

       case 'show_blank':
          die();
       break;

       case 'show_msg':
          echo 'Some custom message';
       break;

       case 'redirect':
          // do redirect
       break;
   }
}
```

With an event you can simplify the readability and keep the code more maintainable:

```
if ($router->isMatched($request)){
   // do dispatch
} else {

   $eventManager->trigger('404_handler');
}
```

while `404_handler` itself looks like

```
  $eventManager->attach('404_handler', function(){

       switch($config->read('404_way_handle')){

           case 'show_blank':
              die();
           break;

           case 'show_msg':
              echo 'Some custom message';
           break;

           case 'redirect':
              // do redirect
           break;
       }

  }, $config);
```

### So let's break it down

1) Events improve readability, which is great for future

2) Events do adhere to the **Single-Responsibility Principle**, because you can simply inject `$eventManager` to your classes that need it, while callback functions could break it or could introduce a **global state** too (Which is bad for unit-testings).

3) There are distinct types of logic - template logic, business logic, error handler logic, data access logic etc etc. Events **do simplify** your application logic by decoupling business (or another kind) logic from its **configuration** logic, so that you end up with clear application logic.

> > You can watch this [lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6dwYklDVp0) if you want to know how they do work in Zend Framework 2 (watch it even if you're not familiar with Zend Framework 2)

**Events in MVC-related architectures**

Since you've been talking about frameworks, its worth nothing to mention, that there could be events in `MVC-related` architectures too. And since events are callback functions you can abstract common `boostrap` events in your MVC-like architecture, like this.

```
$mvcEvent->on(MVC_EVENT::ROUTE_MATCH, function(){

  $mvcEvent->on(MVC_EVENT::DISTPATCH, function($content){

    echo $mvcEvent->trigger(MVC_EVENT::RENDER, $content);

  });

});
```

Note : **In pure MVC theory, there are no events at all**. They do acts as helpers, but again - in frameworks you can abstract them and call them "events".

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me understrand EventManager in ZF2:

> The Event Manager is the component of the framework which allows you to hook in to named events in your application.
>
> There are an existing set of named events in the framework, such as the dispatch event in controllers. You can also create your own as suits your application’s purpose. That’s step one.
> Then, you attach (or listen) to those events. When they fire – or are triggered – your code interrogates the context of the event and responds if needed.

[image]

reference: http://www.maltblue.com/tutorial/zend-framework-2-event-manager-a-gentle-introduction

Comment: in this day of age although complicated in nature observer would be away to go