# How to communicate different modules working with MVC

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, module

I'm trying to work with the following structure in order to implement MVC

[Structure](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_8617736mvc.jpg)

Each module has a controller, a view and a model.

I don't know how to create a communication between different modules. For instance, if I'm running a function within model of `Module1` and I need to get something of the model of `Module2` (in order to comply with MVC), **how could I do or which would it be the correct way to do it?**

Come to my mind do it on this way: Model of Module1 -> Controller of Module1 -> Controller of Module2 -> Model of Module2 -> Controller of Module2 -> Controller of Module1 -> Model of Module1

Comment: Controllers should never need to talk to each other - instead move your shared logic to a shared library.

Comment: "MVC" does not stand for "my very code". It is a architectural design pattern, not a naming convention for files.

Comment: You can treat modules as events. That's basically easiest way of achieving what you need. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17377708/1208233

Answer (score -1):

Model-View-Controllers aren't just MVCs, but as Dai mentioned, you'll also want to include a libraries section of shared logic.

Alternatively, if one controller is derived from another and you're using object-oriented-programming,you may just want to extend one of the controllers. E.g. have a "securePage"
 controller meant for logged in users, and have controllers like "userPanel" and "myProfile"
extend securePage controller.

Or, use both. Have common libraries for functions you're expecting to use *everywhere* and then use class inheritance to provide specialized functions.

Comment: -1: phrases "Model-View-Controllers aren't just MVCs" and "include a libraries section of shared logic" have no meaning. And the responsibility of a controller is to alter the state, and **not** to perform access control.

Comment: Together they do have meaning. I'm saying that the MVC model can include things like libraries, and is not absolutely limited to those 3 types of component. My understanding of his question lead me to believe he thought the model was absolutely rigid, not allowing for libraries to be used. As per the responsibility of the controllers, they are the logic portion of the MVC; Access control does not belong in models and views aren't the right place either. Having a parent controller which automates the verification challenge for their children makes sense; Access control in a controller!

Comment: @user870018 Sounds like you're talking about `Model-View-Presenter`. Access control is called from a Presenter. Controllers also known as `Editors` (see original MVC paper) - they should only care about request variables such as `$_POST`, `$_GET` ...